# Parsing JSON using GSON in Java with multiple root keys with non-repeating values

Tags: java, json, gson

I was able to parse the following JSON using GSON

```
{
  "AMZN": {
    "fundamental": {
      "symbol": "AMZN"
    },
    "symbol": "AMZN",
    "description": "Amazon.com, Inc. - Common Stock",
  }
}
```

I created the following classes to read this data into:

Fundamental.java

```
public class Fundamental {
    
    private String symbol;
    
}
```

Instrument.java

```
public class Instrument{

    private Fundamental fundamental;
    private String description;
    private String symbol;
}
```

Used the following to read data successfully:

```
int startIndex = sb.indexOf("{", 1);
String json = sb.substring(startIndex, sb.length() - 1).strip();
instrument = new Gson().fromJson(json, Instrument.class);
```

The problem I am running into is reading the JSON when symbols repeat. Example JSON below:

```
{
  "AAPL": {
    "fundamental": {
      "symbol": "AAPL"
    },
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "description": "Apple Inc. - Common Stock"
  },
  "AMZN": {
    "fundamental": {
      "symbol": "AMZN"
    },
    "symbol": "AMZN",
    "description": "Amazon.com, Inc. - Common Stock"
  }
}
```

I tried reading this into a Type but does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How does your `Cusip` class look like? You could possibly solve this (if the Instrument names, e.g. "AAPL" and "AMZN", are random) by parsing as `Map<String, Instrument>` instead: `gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Instrument>>() {}.getType())`

Comment: Sorry, Cusip.class is there by mistake should have said Instrument.class.

Comment: Can we count on `fundamental.symbol` being the same as `symbol`?

Comment: Yes. fundamental.symbol will always be the same as symbol.

Comment: Would using `gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Instrument>>() {}.getType())` work for you though? And why are you removing the `{` and the `}` from the JSON?

Comment: The issue is with the symbol of the stock because of which I use the remove of the start of the JSON string to only get the inner content.  This works for single but in case of multiple quotes where there are different symbols at root level my classes fail.